# Prove that this 'generator' function $\boldsymbol{\Psi}$ for cyclic groups is equal to $0$ if $G$ is not cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I came across this question in my Abstract Algebra class, and am having difficulty in proving it.

---

Let $\boldsymbol{\mathcal G}$ be the class of all finite groups. We have a function $\boldsymbol{\Psi}:\boldsymbol{\mathcal{G}}\longrightarrow\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ defined as follows:

\begin{align*}
    \boldsymbol{\Psi}(\{e\}) &= 1,\quad\\
    \boldsymbol{\Psi}(G) &= |G| - \sum_{H< G}\boldsymbol{\Psi}(H).
\end{align*}

We need to show that:

\begin{gather*}
    \boldsymbol{\Psi}(G)=\begin{cases}\;\text{the number of distinct generators if $G$ is cyclic,}\\ \;0\;\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}
\end{gather*}

---

My attempt:

I have proven the first part, that $\boldsymbol{\Psi}(G)$ is equal to the number of generator if $G$ is cyclic: this follows directly from the fundamental theorem of cyclic groups along with the following result related to Euler's Totient: $$n = \sum_{d\mid n}\phi(d)$$

Unfortunately, however, I have no idea how to prove that $\boldsymbol{\Psi}(G)=0$ if $G$ is not cyclic.

- I have tried and found the result true for all groups of orders $4$ and $6$, but that hasn't really given me any new intuition apart from the fact that induction on $|G|$ may be helpful here, but I can't see how the induction hypothesis helps.
- By Cauchy's Theorem we know there exist elements of order $p$ for all prime $p\mid |G|$, however the key issue seems to lie in the fact that *how many* such elements are there in any group depends on the nature of the group and is unpredictable.
- Finally, I suppose the fact that every element of $G$ generates a proper subgroup may be helpful.

How do I proceed?

Comment: If you use induction, you can assume the result holds for all the subgroups appearing in the sum. That simplifies it (but there is still some work to do).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I've understood that part, but I don't see how it is helpful since the prime subgroups don't disappear.

Comment: You get left with exactly the cyclic subgroups. Now, the claim that the result should be $0$ can be translated into the claim that each element in the group is a generator for exactly one proper cyclic subgroup.